# Formulas overlap text and sidebar

Tags: bug, mathjax

Found an annoying bug:
going [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340435/how-to-solve-it-perhaps-with-taylor?noredirect=1#comment2724532_1340435) gets you this:

[image]

If you remove the end bit then it's ok.

Chrome version 43.0.2357.130 (64-bit)

Comment: Displayed fine for me just now. It has nothing to do with the link to the comment. Sometimes when you visit a page, something screws up the MathJax rendering. Reload the page and it is fine (so far it worked for me every time). But it's good to have the bug reported here, I always was too lazy.

Comment: I have experienced the same on Firefox (currently version 38.0.5) a handful of times. The remedy suggested by Daniel has always worked - not always on my first attempt though.

Comment: @Daniel, Jyrki: This seems to happen when you "show additional comments" on Jax-heavy pages, which pushes some of the layout down, and apparently the MathJax rendered classes remain afloat, and thus out of place. It is possible that the OP has a much weaker device than any of us three (at the moment), which causes this to become a problem.

Comment: I've edited this title, and another one on main site. Please choose titles that  describe the actual problem. [Suggestions on how to do this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/10144#10144)