# Redundant overlapping expressions in review queues when closing as duplicates

Tags: bug, mathjax, review, exact-duplicates

Since this is already more than six months this has been reported inside the [Mathematics new site theme is live](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28842/mathematics-new-site-theme-is-live/28875#28875) topic, and yet still not fixed, I've decided to put this one separately.

If you go to review queues, review question that has flagged duplicate, click to Close, select duplicate of, then you will see redundant/overlapping expressions like this:

[image]

This happens at least in Chrome 68.0.3440.106, also in IE 11.0.9600.19100. It's also worth mentioning it happens in every single case if the duplicate has mathjax in it, not just occasionally. This is not one time occurrence, happens almost always when there is and equation.

Also in the referenced topic I've mentioned some ways to "fix" it on client side (I have no idea if that is a proper way to fix that):

Turns out that typesetting is invoked indeed twice from different parts of code. First is through `MathJax.Hub.Typeset(this)` in **stub.en.js**

```
"mathjax": function() {
                return this.each(function() {
                    "undefined" != typeof MathJax && MathJax.Hub.Typeset(this)
                })
            },
```

and second one is in **full.en.js** through `styleCode()`:

```
var t = e.find(".list-originals");
            return 0 == t.children().length ? (t.hide(), void 0) : (t.show(), h(t, !0), styleCode(), t.find(".item").click(function() {
```

For a test I have removed above call to `styleCode()` from the **full.en.js**, and the issue went away, without noticing any side effects so far.

Similar issues (although not giving reproducible scenario):

- [Formulas overlap text and sidebar](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20867/formulas-overlap-text-and-sidebar)
- [Double display of formulas](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21213/double-display-of-formulas)

Can someone maybe fix this?

Comment: Calls to `MathJax.Hub.Typeset()` should always be made through `MathJax.Hub.Queue()` in order to prevent clashes between the calls.  So using `MathJax.Hub.Queue('Typeset', MathJax.Hub, this)` might resolve the issue.